# Why is androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.offscreenPageLimit generating error Must be one of ViewPager2.OFFSCREEN_PAGE_LIMIT_DEFAULT

Tags: android-studio

Im using ViewPager2 in my current Android project.
When trying to set offscreenLimit via a constant as follows :

```
    companion object {
            private const val NUM_PAGES: Int = 4
        }

...

 viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = NUM_PAGES
```

I receive the following error
[image]

however when I use a simple numerical value of 4 it is accepted, e.g.

```
 viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 4
```

Why is a constant not accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also facing the same issue, but after fiddling around with code, I able to make it work.

```
companion object {
        private const val NUM_PAGES: Int = 4 // will not work
        @JvmStatic private val NUM_PAGES: Int = 4 // will work

}
```

The reason why @JvmStatic works is perhaps the underlayer ViewPager2 is still in Java, so it can use constant as we expected it to be.

Comment: This does not work on my side. I have to let the variable out of companion object like this: `private val NUM_PAGES: Int = 4 // will work` then it won't lint error anymore.